# why does sub query with group by do full scan twice?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am testing two types of queries.
The first type looks like below:

```
explain select * from ord_order;  

explain select * from (select * from ord_order) as tbl;
```

These two execution plan shows the same behavior (full scan once).

However, the second type looks like below:

```
explain select * from ord_order 
        group by bundle_or_order_number;  

explain select * from 
        (select * from ord_order 
         group by bundle_or_order_number) as tbl;
```

the second query do the full scan twice!

Can someone explain it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, it doesn't matter because your queries are malformed.  Don't use `select *` with `group by`.  It just doesn't make sense -- and current versions of MySQL do not support it.  The question is:  What rows do the columns come from?  You should be using aggregation functions.

Why are the two queries different?  In MySQL lingo, the difference is whether or not the derived table (a subquery in the `from` clause) is materialized.  Whether or not subqueries are materialized depends on the nature of the subquery and what MySQL decides to do in the version you are using.

You can read about optimizing derived tables in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-table-optimization.html).

Comment: and current versions of MySQL do not support it - unfortunately, they still do. It's just the default setting that changed :(

Comment: @Shadow . . . Somehow, I assume that people who use such constructs are not advanced enough to understand server settings.

Comment: if it comes to relaxing some constraints they deem unnecessary, you would be surprised... my favourite was a guy, who set the group_concat buffer beyond the capacity of the physical memory and was surprised when his MySQL server crashed :)